# how to GetValue from the class using reflection,c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a two class

```
class FOO
{
    public string Id{get;set;}

    public Model Model{get;set}
}

class Model
{
    public string Id
}
```

I need to access `foo.Model.Id` in extension methods

Consider in the extension method `T` is the type that we pass for `FOO`

I can able to access `T.GetType().GetProperty("Model").GetValue(instance, null);`

But how to access the `Foo.Model.Id`?

Comment: You repeat the process with the instance of the `Model` you just got.

Comment: The result is a model instance. Do the same with it to get the ID. Better yet, use `dynamic` to avoid the entire mess. Such code does look very strange though *and* it will be awfully slow. Perhaps you should use generics, pass an interface instead of a concrete class, or both. Or you can pass an accessor lambda to retrive the value without using reflection

Comment: Or differently, restrict `T` to some base class type or an interface.

Comment: Can you post your complete extension method? Maybe this can be done without reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to repeat your original statement for the next object down:

```
public static int GetId<T>(this T obj)
{
    var model = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Model").GetValue(instance, null);
    return (int)(model.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(instance, null));
}
```

But why you would want to put this in a generic extension method is debatable. This is a very specific property chain, so doesn't really make much sense.

A simpler way to do it would be to use `dynamic` - you don't need an extension method at all then:

```
dynamic d = obj;
int id = obj.Model.Id;
```

Or better use an interface:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    Model Model {get;set;}
}

public class Foo : IFoo 
{
    public string Id{get;set;}

    public Model Model{get;set}
}

public static int GetId(this IFoo obj)
{
    return obj.Model.Id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do the same thing a second time:

```
var model = instance.GetType().GetProperty("Model").GetValue(instance, null);
var id = model.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(model, null);
```